# Need good free HTML5 video player for integrating video ads and Vimeo videos

Tags: video-player, vimeo

We're trying to implement ads on our video platform. Could you recommend a reliable HTML5 video player that works with Vimeo, compatible with the VAST standards? I've already tried video.js and checked out jw player. Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Hi Marina, what research (e.g. internet search) did you do to find a suitable HTML5 video player? Can you please include that in your question? This prevents that answers suggest something which you already found and deemed not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you looking at the built-in HTML5 outstream video player [AdPlayer.Pro](https://adplayer.pro/). 
You can use this video ad player and host your video on AdPlayer.Pro platform or you can use HTML5 player separately. It's compliant with all major video advertising standards, like VAST/VPAID and Google IMA. Also I like the UI and additional tracking tool, which provides watch time, click rate, estimated revenue etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for recommendation. I've decided to try this out. I've already implemented HTML5 video player by AdPlayer.Pro on my site. I'd like to enable some features for visitors after they complete watching rewarded video ads implemented according to [https://adplayer.pro/solutions/rewarded](https://adplayer.pro/solutions/rewarded). What event should my code 'listen to' to identify 100% ad view rate? I'm using the 'complete' event but it's not working so far.

`document.getElementById("player").addEventListener("complete", function(){....my logic ....});`

Comment: Think, you should use the 'AdStopped' event in this case. Find out more here https://docs.adplayer.pro/whitelabel-standalone-script/api-reference/